# Using different datatypes in C# MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I seek clarification, i understand when to use data types of **string, integer, double** etc.**When exactly would i use a data type of var (Variable)?**

Comment: When ever you want.Refer [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: `var` isn't a data type.  It's shorthand to tell the compiler to use the correct type without you needing to specify it.